# .htaccess rewriterule and fake directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do some URL rewriting with Apache and PHP. This is for SEO reasons so that foo.com/product-category/product-title becomes foo.com/product.php?id=999. I would of course want the URL not to change and be the SEO friendly version.

I have a current site which has a working setup but it's very much a hack rather than a maintainable solution, so I am trying to do things right!

At the moment I have:-

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\%]+)/?($) /url_redirect.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which works perfectly, http://foo.com/random-url?foo=1&bar=2 ends up at /url_redirect.php with $_GET['page'] = 'random-url' and $_GET['foo'] = 1 etc etc..

I want the exactly the same thing to happen if you one level deeper
(eg http://foo.com/non-existing-directory/random-url?foo=1&bar=2)

I *could* make the non-existing-directoy a real directory and then .htaccess from there but there has to be a easer way.. I would prefer me not to have to hardcode any directory names (which is sort of how my current solution works).

I think the issue is probably something not right with the regular expression, they always defeat me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this, might not be the best way to achieve it though (I'm no rewrite guru)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\%]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\%]+)?($) url_redirect.php?page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\%]+)/?($) url_redirect.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Sorry that was for my local setup here's how I think you would want it!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\%]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\%]+)?($) /url_redirect.php?page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\%]+)/?($) /url_redirect.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Notice the / before url_redirect.php

Comment: Yep this worked perfectly! you have saved me from a nasty symlink php hack job!, I guess I could go one level deeper with another /([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\%]+) but I can't see me wanted to go that deep into .htaccess inception

Comment: You could yes but along with adding the extra /([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\%]+) you also change the last bit to page=$3 (from page=$2)

Comment: I worked that bit out all by myself and got it working.. not that I want to use it, but it's good to have options.